# Error while copying records from table1 to table 2. sqlite constraint exception error code 19 constraint failed

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm copying  all the records (back up) from table1 to table2 in the same database. This is my first database application.

Here is the table 1 structure :

```
private static final String CREATE_SELECTED_CAND_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE if not exists "
        + TABLE_SELECTED_CAND
        + "("
        + KEY_ID
        + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
        + KEY_NAME1
        + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NAME2
        + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NAME3
        + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NAME4
        + " TEXT," + KEY_NAME5 + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Table2 Structure :

```
private static final String CREATE_SELECTED_CAND_RECOUNT1 = " CREATE TABLE if not exists "
        + TABLE_RECOUNT1
        + "("
        + KEY_ID
        + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
        + KEY_NAME1
        + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NAME2
        + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NAME3
        + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NAME4
        + " TEXT," + KEY_NAME5 + " TEXT" + ")";
```

and I am copying like this :

```
    mDb.execSQL(" INSERT INTO " + TABLE_RECOUNT1 + " SELECT * FROM "
            + TABLE_SELECTED_CAND);
```

Now the problem is, ***It is copying only if all the columns are not null***  I have some columns as null, but I want to copy them also. How do I achieve this.?  Any help would be highly appreciable..!

These are the stack traces :

> E/AndroidRuntime(30294):
>      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: *error code 19:
>      constraint failed*
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:92)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:2028)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1968)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at com.dana.db.SelectedCandidatesDB.copyToRecount1(SelectedCandidatesDB.java:257)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at com.dana.votecount.VoteRecount.fetchAllFromRecount1(VoteRecount.java:161)   E/AndroidRuntime(30294):     at com.dana.votecount.VoteRecount.access$1(VoteRecount.java:158)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30294):    at com.dana.votecount.VoteRecount$2$1.onClick(VoteRecount.java:107)

Comment: Could you please show the export of the table structure so that we can see the contraints in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually possible [to set autoincrement columns to a specific value](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), but only if that value does not yet exist.

It is likely that the records already exist in the `RECOUNT1` table.

To ensure that there are no old records, delete them before inserting:

```
mDb.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_RECOUNT1);
mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_RECOUNT1 + " SELECT ...");
```

Alternatively, if you know that none of the records have changed, you can use the [INSERT OR IGNORE command](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) to insert only those records whose IDs do not yet exist in the target table:

```
mDb.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + TABLE_RECOUNT1 + " SELECT ...");
```

Comment: works like a charm..! Hearty thanks "CL" I used your 1st suggestion. Deleting the table and inserting into the table!

Answer (score 0):

the error is due to the **autoincrement** because you can not or assign give value to column which is autoincrement you should assign null or change in the query

mDb.execSQL(" INSERT INTO " + TABLE_RECOUNT1 + " SELECT * FROM "
            + TABLE_SELECTED_CAND);

replce * with column names not mention autoincrement column name and also for table1 in the same query

Comment: I'm supposed to delete a row with this id only. i cannot assign _id as null.. How can i change this query to achieve the above..!